# HTACCESS resulting in error 404

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following htaccess codes in a subdirectory

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+).html$ order-details.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

It works fine. The problem is every other page in that directory gives an error 404.

The link example.com/sub/sub/123456.html works fine. Also, example.com/sub/sub/ works fine since I have an index file in the sub directory. However, example.com/sub/sub/anotherpage.html gives error 404. Deleting the htaccess solves one problem and brings the other.

example.com/sub/sub/

Comment: So basically you want `123456.html` to go to the `order-details.php` page, but `anotherpage.html ` to just show the **real** anotherpage.html  page that exists in that directory?

Comment: Yes exactly thats how I want it

Answer (score 1):

You can add

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

To your code to make sure to ignore files that exists in your folder.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+).html$ order-details.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Well, its funny, it works for all other files apart from one :-o

Comment: Are you sure the filename is correct? This code should work.

Comment: Yes. The file name is correct. If I delete the htaccess code, the link works fine.

Comment: The `.htaccess` file is inside the `sub/sub/` folder? Do you have some other configurations there? Which version of apache you use?

Comment: I just checked this in my server and it works great.

Comment: Actually, no page works :-( the other pages that seemed to be working were redirecting just like order id because I had changed to alphanumeric. Changing my code back numberic only, all other pages are giving the error 404. 

Yes I have a the htaccess file in `sub/sub/` no other configuration in that file but I have other configurations in the main directory

Comment: what are the configurations in the main directory? and which version of apache?

Comment: In on xampp v3.2.2 

the other configurations are

Comment: In on xampp v3.2.2 

the other configurations are

ServerSignature Off

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =POST
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^forums/ - [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]

Options -Indexes
IndexIgnore *

Options -ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .php .pl .py .jsp .asp .htm .shtml .sh .cgi

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

Comment: Update the question with the that. It's impossible to read it in the comment.

Comment: I got the solution. It looks like I had to remove .php extension in the htaccess file in `sub/sub/` too. Including lines to get rid of .php extension solved the problem. Thanks a lot

Comment: Sure @Dekel. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

You tried to access to page with alphanumeric name.
But, on your htaccess it's only for numeric ones.

`RewriteRule ^([0-9]+).html$ order-details.php?id=$1 [NC,L]`
Access only numerical names due to `[0-9]`

If you want to redirect **alpha**numerical, you have to use another mask. Maybe `[0-9A-Za-z]` ?

Comment: The page I renamed is numeric. Like stated above, 123456.html to go to the order-details.php page, but anotherpage.html to just show the **real** anotherpage.html page that exists in that directory

Answer (score 0):

Works now. It looks like I had to remove the .php extension in the htaccess in `sub/sub/` too.